# GitKit Java client library – emailVerify status of account with Facebook as provider

Tags: java, facebook, google-identity-toolkit

I was testing the following scenario. Sign in with **GitKit** and use **Facebook** as the provider.

All works well, but and the token cookie contains a.o.: *"provider_id":"facebook.com","verified":false*

Note that verified is false, albeit *Facebook* emails are verified by *Facebook*. I understand if *GitKit* might not want to hard code this assumption, but..

If we then send the user a verification email from our server using `getEmailVerificationLink(gitkitUser.getEmail())` again all goes well.
(link is `.../signin.html?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=sFKXzFsKQ4ckr4A-HtofNPkRq_A&apb.cs=1`)

The user sees "*Success! Your email address has been verified.*"

But when then redirected to our server the token cookie still says "verified:false"!

My question is if this is the expected behavior? 
Because if it is then I don't get it and I would very much appreciate some clarification.

Note, if I sign in with a simple password account, then the token cookie does give "*verified:true*" after the user followed the `getEmailVerificationLink()`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug for social login account. The verified flag should be true after the verification. I will update here once we confirm the root cause.